# twitter search api no place returned

Tags: geolocation, twitter

I am having a bit of trouble sifting through the twitter API. I am trying to search for tweets near a certain location and then see their exact (or approximate) geo coordinates. I understand the geo field is deprecated and now we are supposed to use the "place" field. Unfortunately when I use the following url: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&geocode=30.1829,-97.832,10mi I get a bunch of responses with a location that matches the city of the geo coordinates, but geo: is null and there is no place field. Am I stuck with only having an accuracy up to city coordinates, or am I using the wrong search call?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, tweeting with a geo location is an opt-in process.  Twitter will supply a feed from the area for all tweeters in that area, but only those who have opted to tweet their coordinates will show up with "geo" info.

Using q=here with your url it did return 1 tweet for me with "geo" info in this form (though likely it will have moved on down the timeline by the time you try...):

```
"geo":{"coordinates":[-33.9769,18.5080],"type":"Point"}
```

Comment: I understand why the geo info is often empty.  Even those with the geo field filled in do not have places.  Even checkins from 4 Square do not have places.  The places are always empty.

Comment: It appears the place is not in the Json returned from twitter.  It must just be part of the Twitter4j library we are using.

Answer (score 0):

Every user has a user defined location set in their profile settings. Use this when users don't use geo-encoding.

You can obtain a list of all countries / states by country and do a simple clean-up operation on the dataset.

This gave me what I needed for location data and greatly enriched my output.